# Issue Inserting value only if does not already exist in table

Tags: mysql, orm, coldfusion

I am reading a spreadsheet into a query. Then inserting the values into a database table. I only want to perform the insert if one of the values ie PartNumber does not already exist in the target table.

I am using the code below to check for duplicates first. However, I am still running into an issue with duplicates when inserting into the `itemPN` column, which does not allow duplicate values.

If I refresh the page below, it will insert a few dozen more values and hang because of another duplicate.  If I refresh it 4 times or so, it will insert the 117 records I need. I am confused about why the code works sometimes, but other times fails. It seems to hang up on the same rows on each attempt. Different attempts at formatting the variables have created the same results.

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" 
     src="#downloadDir#import.xls" 
     query="qxldata" 
     excludeheaderrow="yes" 
     columnnames="PartNumber,Name,Price,Category,IsActive,Location,Description,remarks,SubLocation">

<cfoutput query="qxldata" startrow="3">
   <cfset xlPN=qxldata.PartNumber>

   <cfquery name="noDup">
      SELECT * 
      FROM   Items
      WHERE  itemPN = #xlPN#
   </cfquery>

   <cfif NOT noDup.RecordCount EQ 1>
       <cfscript>
          //Insert a new item
          item = new items();
          item.setitemPN(PartNumber);
          item.setitemName(Name);
          item.setitemCategory(Category);
          item.setitemDescription(Description);
          item.setitemBarcodeName("bc"&PartNumber&".jpg");
          item.setitemImageName(PartNumber&".jpg");
          item.setitemReorderPoint(NumberFormat("", 0.00));
          item.setitemReorderQuantity(NumberFormat("", 0.00));
          item.setitemLocation(Location);
          item.setitemSubLocation(SubLocation);
          item.setitemLength(NumberFormat("", 0.00));
          item.setitemWidth(NumberFormat("", 0.00));
          item.setitemHeight(NumberFormat("", 0.00));
          item.setitemRemarks(remarks);
          item.setitemIsActive(IsActive);
          item.setitemVendorID("1");
          item.setitemPrice(NumberFormat(Price, 0.00));
          EntitySave(item);
       </cfscript>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot like this:

```
<cfoutput query="qxldata" startrow="3" maxrows="3">
<cfset xlPN=qxldata.PartNumber>
 #xlPN# <br>
</cfoutput>
```

You will most likely see three identical values.  You can solve that problem by specifying the row number your want,

```
<cfset xlPN=qxldata.PartNumber[currentrow]>
```

Or skipping that variable altogether and changing this:

```
WHERE itemPN = #xlPN#
```

to this:

```
WHERE itemPN = #PartNumber#
```

or better yet, to this:

```
WHERE itemPN = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#PartNumber#">
```

Comment: If I output:"#qxldata.PartNumber#,#PartNumber#,#noDup.RecordCount#", I get paired numbers along with the noDup recordcount.  When an error throws, I'll get two sets of this "3032,3032,0".  The numbers appear to be identical but I have tried trims etc. to try to ensure they are viewed the same by coldfusion.  If I hit refresh on the browser, mySQL will be happy with the inserted number but another one will throw the error.  I changed my code to match your last "WHERE" statement, but is as if processing doesn't consistently notice the first insert when it looks for the record on the next loop?